# How to reverse GRAL axis (java data plots)

Tags: java, swing

I would like to plot a XY dataset with the Y and or X data reversed (eg y axis has highest value at bottom, smallest at top). Is there a way to do this in GRAL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reverse an axis of an `XYPlot` in GRAL, you can simply reverse the shape in the respective `AxisRenderer`:

```
AxisRenderer axisRenderer = xyPlot.getAxisRenderer(XYPlot.AXIS_X);
axisRenderer.setShapeDirectionSwapped(true);
```

This also works with fancy axes whose shapes are more sophisticated than plain lines.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to reverse your data, since there is no option (in my view) to reverse axis in GRAL.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

Reversing the shape in AxisRenderer worked a treat and is preferable to reversing the data.

(Previously I did end up trying 
`plot.getAxis("x").setRange(max, min);`
This reversed the axis however the axis labels were lost and appear to overprint each other at the x/y axis intersection.)